# Enterprise Architect: Associate operations

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to associate two operations. I am able to create an association between two classes, but I don't know how to bind the assotiation directly to a class operation. Please see the picture below.

Connector type: Assotiation
Destination component type: Operation

[image: Assotiation to a class type and to an operation type]

Answer (score 2):

Found in [EA documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/modeling_basics/connect_to_element_feature.html). Right click on the end of connector, choose "Link to element feature" and the dialog appears.

[image]

Comment: This is perfectly correct. You should note, however, that these feature-to-feature links are not really permitted by UML, and consequently their implementation in EA is a little obscure. So using SQL or EA's API for accessing (this aspect of) the model is somewhat cumbersome (but by no means impossible).